# Overriding isEnabled in UIControl to still allow touches

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol

I have a custom slider which inherits from `UIControl`.

For my control, the `isEnabled` state should still allow touches, but when I override `isEnabled` it seems `UIControl` is also setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to false.

No matter what I do I can't seem to prevent this. Any ideas, or am I stuck with creating another name for my state (i.e. `isBypassed`)?

```
class CustomSlider: UIControl {

    private var _isEnabled: Bool = false

    override public var isEnabled: Bool {
        get { return _isEnabled }
        set { setIsEnabled(newValue, animated: false }
    }

    public func setIsEnabled(_ isEnabled: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        self._isEnabled = isEnabled
        if animated {
            //do the animation...
        }
    }

}
```

P.S. If you are wondering why I want this, it's because a disabled control should still be able to identify itself when touched: it lights up briefly but then quickly dies away indicating that it needs to be enabled in order to allow further interaction.

If I want to block all user interaction, I will use `isUserInteractionEnabled`.

Comment: Can you expand a little on what you mean by "identify itself"? There might be another built-in way to do that, depending on what it is.

Comment: Thanks. Added more info.

Comment: Have you tried the opposite? One could argue that a disabled control is disabled, but an enabled control should be able to identify itself even if user interaction is turned off. Have you tried overriding *isUserInteractionEnabled* instead of *isEnabled*?

Comment: I have 3 of these sliders, and they all are "greyed out" when the app starts up. The user then goes into "Enable Controls Mode", and taps the slider they want to enable, which then brings them to life. So (in my case) 'isEnabled' seems like much better semantics since the user can still interact with a disabled control. If it's just a matter of naming , the next best word I could come up with is 'isActivated' or 'isActive'.

Answer (score 0):

The only approach I could think of is to set the slider to grey with `0.5 alpha` (You can adjust the alpha to make it look like disabled).

Also, create a `BOOL` property to identify its state (active/inactive)

So when the user touches on the slider it will still respond to `valueChanged:` (whatever selector you give to it)